# How do I find the mean of columns from different txt files?

Tags: r, loops, import, lapply

New at R, I've looked at previous posts but can't get it to work. I need the mean of `V4` (variable/column from each table) from each table. Ideally I need a final table with the mean of V4 from each table . here's the code I have so far:

```
file_list <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "*.txt") 

r <- llply(file_list, read.table, skip = 1)
```

there are 111 txt files all in the one folder, I've read all the files except for the first row because its unusable. thanks!

Comment: Can we get the output of `dput(r)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lapply` reads creates a list of data frames, one for each file read. If you want to get only the mean of V4 for each then try:

```
file_list <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "*.txt") 

r <- lapply(file_list, FUN = function(x){
                                df = read.table(x, skip=1)
                                mean(df$V4)
                             })
```

In this `lapply`, `x` is a file name from `file_list`. Its contents are read into `df` (with the same options you used) and then the mean of V4 is calculated. You'll get a list having the same length as `file_list`. If you want a vector instead, change the `lapply` to a `sapply`.

If the V4 column has any NA, you'll get the same result, if you want to skip NAs when calculating the mean add the option `na.rm = T` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Only guessing the output of your data but this works for me:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list %>% 
  mutate(var4_mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.$var4)))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
              data var4_mean
            <list>     <dbl>
1 <tibble [3 x 4]> 489.23667
2 <tibble [3 x 4]>  56.56667
```

Just in case you want a single mean value for all of `var4` in its entirety, you can do that with this:

```
df_list %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  summarise(var4_mean = mean(var4))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  var4_mean
      <dbl>
1  272.9017
```

If you want to try this out with a reproducible example, run this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- tibble(
  var1 = c(1423, 3222, 2131),
  var2 = c(6.27, 26.4, 18.1),
  var3 = c(1461, 2112, 2531),
  var4 = c(614.2, 22.41, 831.1)
)

df_2 <- tibble(
  var1 = c(14, 22, 31),
  var2 = c(6.2, 2.4, 8.1),
  var3 = c(141, 212, 231),
  var4 = c(64.2, 22.4, 83.1)
)

df_1 <- nest(df_1)
df_2 <- nest(df_2)

df_list <- list(df_1, df_2)
df_list <- bind_rows(df_list)
df_list

# Unnest the data frames and compute mean of entire var4
df_list %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  summarise(var4_mean = mean(var4))

# Compute mean of var4 for each individual data frame
df_list %>% 
  mutate(var4_mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.$var4)))
```

I recommend reading this chapter from [R4DS](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). It's a great read on nested data frames.